# cluetip plug-in on jQuery loaded nods

Tags: jquery, cluetip

This is the scenario:

The user clicks on e.g. a button, that loads (using jQuery) a node, e.g.

```
'<span id="selected" title="|click to reselect">selected: #' + id + '</span>'
```

Then goes jQuery (for cluetip) code:

```
$('#selected').cluetip({splitTitle: '|', showTitle: false});
```

Cluetip applied to that jQuery loaded node does not fire.

Anyone knows the solution?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you reapplying the plugin `cluetip` after you create the `<span>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#container').append('<span id="selected">...</span>');
    $('#selected').cluetip();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your reference to ClueTip at the bottom of your page, not in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cluetip url here"></script>
```